# Purescript Tutorial: unknown value logShow

Tags: purescript

I am about an hour into learning PureScript and I've hit a snag going through the [PureScript by Example Tutorial](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read#leanpub-auto-computing-diagonals) which PureScript recommended on their site. (Specifically I'm in section 2.10). I have managed to get everything installed and I am attempting to use the `logShow` method they describe in the tutorial. I am getting an `Unknown value logShow` error when I run this code:

```
module Main where

import Prelude
import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (CONSOLE, log)
import Math (sqrt)

main :: forall e. Eff (console :: CONSOLE | e) Unit
main = logShow (diagonal 3.0 4.0)

diagonal w h = sqrt(w * w + h * h)
```

I assume that `logShow` is a method intended to log an integer since the actual `log` method only takes strings. Where is this method defined? Am I failing to import something? Is my installation incorrect? Or is the tutorial skipping something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're almost there.

Notice this line:

```
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (CONSOLE, log)
```

`Control.Monad.Eff.Console` offers both `log` and `logShow`. To solve your particular problem, you just need to replace `log` between those parens with `logShow` (the first name after the `(`, `CONSOLE`, is the name of Effect).

Just in case -- The difference between the two can be seen by the types:

```
log     :: forall eff.        String -> Eff (console :: CONSOLE | eff) Unit
logShow :: forall a eff. Show a => a -> Eff (console :: CONSOLE | eff) Unit
```

Ignoring the effects for a moment...

```
log ::                    String -> Unit
logShow :: forall a. Show a => a -> Unit
```

`log` only prints strings, while `logShow` prints anything that has a `Show` instance.

Realistically, yes; it means `logShow` is simply `(log <<< show)`. And if we go look at the source... [We can find it's indeed the case](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-console/blob/v1.0.0/src/Control/Monad/Eff/Console.purs#L21).